# Is there a way for lazy loading with FlowRow?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-accompanist

I use FlowRow in the accompanist project to auto wrap my text items to next line.  It works as intended.  However, when I have a large dataset (which I already load with paging), I don't find an api like LazyColumn to load and build the items as needed, if I loop through the pager flow, it tries to load to build everything at once.  Any adice please?

```
lazyPagingItems = pager.flow.collectAsLazyPagingItems()

FlowRow(
 ) {
    val items = lazyPagingItems
    for (index in 1..items.itemCount-1) {
        Text(
            text = word,
            maxLines = 1
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: No  I end up using it just for small dataset.  For larger dataset, I have to use the grid.

Comment: And how do you handle lines with different item quantity?

Comment: Unfortunately with grid it's fixed number of items for every line.

Answer (score 0):

Little late to the party. But it seems you could use `LazyVerticalGrid` or `LazyHorizontalGrid` in adaptive mode like below.

```kotlin
LazyVerticalGrid(
    columns = GridCells.Adaptive(/* item min size */)
) {
    // Items
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's now have a lazy loading component called ContextualFlowRow and ContextualFlowColumn.

It lazy loads until the maxLines or maxHeight.

```
@Composable
@ExperimentalLayoutApi
fun ContextualFlowRow(
    itemCount: Int,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    horizontalArrangement: Arrangement.Horizontal = Arrangement.Start,
    verticalArrangement: Arrangement.Vertical = Arrangement.Top,
    maxItemsInEachRow: Int = Int.MAX_VALUE,
    maxLines: Int = Int.MAX_VALUE,
    overflow: ContextualFlowRowOverflow = ContextualFlowRowOverflow.Clip,
    content: @Composable ContextualFlowRowScope.(index: Int) -> Unit
): Unit
```

[Link](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/package-summary#ContextualFlowRow)